# angularJS different arrows for orderBy

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my app i have table, which i'm sorting

```
<th data-ng-click="predicate = 'FirstName'; reverse=!reverse">Name <i ng-class="{'arrow-down' : reverse, 'arrow-up' : !reverse}"></i></th>
<th data-ng-click="predicate = 'LastName'; reverse=!reverse">Last Name <i ng-class="{'arrow-down' : reverse, 'arrow-up' : !reverse}"></i</th>
```

and ng-repeat:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="user in users | orderBy:predicate:reverse" data-id="{{user.Id}}" class="table-row">
```

how could i display differeng ng-class for item, when i't column is sorted?

now it appear for whole columns...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the `predicate` to the `ng-class` condition:

```
<th data-ng-click="predicate = 'FirstName'; reverse=!reverse">Name
    <i ng-class="{'arrow-down' : reverse && predicate==='FirstName', 'arrow-up' : !reverse && predicate==='FirstName'}"></i></th>
```

---

Having a default arrow showing when the table is not sorted by this column is as simple:

```
<th data-ng-click="predicate = 'FirstName'; reverse=!reverse">Name
    <i ng-class="{
        'arrow-down' : reverse && predicate==='FirstName',
        'arrow-up' : !reverse && predicate==='FirstName',
        'arrow-not-sorted': predicate!=='FirstName'
    }"></i></th>
```

Comment: What do you mean? Can you reproduce it in a fiddle/plunk?

Comment: no, could not reproduce
i mean that it must by default show something, like bottom down or up

Comment: what i mean: what would be if i have three other fields with sorting too? when i click on them i will lose all classes, becouse reverse && predicate==='FirstName'  is false and !reverse && predicate==='FirstName' is false how to be than? how to put always def value?

Comment: If you click on a column, the table is sorted by that column. So that column gets the arrow, while the previous - if any - looses it. You may want multiple column sorting, but it is not mentioned in the question and it is quite a different problem - you will have to provide more details.

Comment: maybe: `<th data-ng-click="predicate = 'FirstName'; reverse=!reverse">Name <i ng-class="{'arrow-down' : reverse && predicate==='FirstName', 'arrow-up' : !reverse && predicate==='FirstName', 'arrow-down' : predicate!=='FirstName'}"></i></th>
                    <th data-ng-click="predicate = 'LastName'; reverse=!reverse">Last Name <i ng-class="{'arrow-down' : reverse && predicate==='LastName', 'arrow-up' : !reverse && predicate==='LastName', 'arrow-down' : predicate!=='LastName'}"></i></th>` similaar to this?